# How to run wallch in "random time" mode automatically on startup?

Tags: desktop-background, background-process

I just discovered wallch and I installed it on my Ubuntu 12.04. I really like it.
Now, I would like to use the "change wallpaper in random time (2-20) minutes" option on startup.

I enable the "startup option" in the preferences menu, to allow Wallch runs every time I do login, and a Wallch item is automatically added to my Startup Application Preferences. Looking at it, it runs the program with the option --constant, instead of "random".

It doesn't seem to exist any option on the command line to start the program in the "random time" mode. Is there a way?

Comment: please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the developers of Wallch and I assure you that this is not possible :D

On our new version we plan to add something like that in our to-do list, though :)

Also, you will be able to adjust your very own time selection, not only between 2-20 minutes !

**EDIT:**

I just updated the 3+ versions of Wallch that we are releasing (before the 4th that we are planning to include into 12.10) and it is able to start at startup depending on what is your preference.

For example, if in the program you have set to run with random time and with random images, it will do exactly the same on startup etc.

You can install this version of Wallch by giving the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/3+
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Also, in this version of Wallch you are able to set your own random time (not only between 2-20 mins)